# How to update database when some one leave the video calling in tokbox

Tags: php, tokbox

Actually when my user or psychic will closed browser or tab  then I am not able to detect him

I have used you session destroyed or another session destroyed function

like

`session.on("connectionDestroyed", function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
       displayConnectionstatus();
    });`

But they are not working. So Please guide me how can I update my database on connection lost

Answer (score 0):

Indresh,

You can use below code to detect when a stream is destroyed or leaves the session:

```
session.on("streamDestroyed", function (event) {
      console.log("Stream stopped. Reason: " + event.reason);
    });
```

See the relevant documentation here: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/subscribe-stream/js/#detect_streams_leave_session

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Can you please tell me how can I will full screen of video calling